# What is contained in $E_{x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I can't exactly understand what is contained in  $E_x$. As I think of it, $E_x$ contains distinct points $r$, for which the below holds. But since the author states that the interval $(0,r)$ is contained in $E_x$ i'm confused.
[image]

Comment: Okay so. Is it ALL those $r$ which satify the above?. So it is infinitely many $r's$ for each $x$?

Comment: Yes, all those $r$.

Comment: When it says "the interval $(0,r)$ is _included_ in $E_x$" this means contained as a subset, not contained as an element.  The elements of $E_x$ are real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

That the interval $(0, r)$ is contained in $E_x$ just says $s \in (0, r)$ implies $s \in E_x$. In other words, that whenever $0 < s < r$, we have $B_s(x) \subseteq E_x$.

Notice that if $r \in E_x$, then we have the inclusions $B_s(x) \subseteq B_r(x) \subseteq E_x$, so that also $B_s(x) \subseteq E_x$, i.e., $s \in E_x$ if $r \in E_x$ and $0 < s < r$.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I guess that was what I tried to explain "non-mathematical" in my comment.